# Visual Studio 2022 branch checkout doesn't ask what to do with changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

Normally it would ask whether to keep changes, stash changes or discard changes. But now it keeps changes and there is no prompt.

I looked for settings in options and couldn't find anything.

How do I fix this?

**Edit:**

This happens when the changes consists of only added files.